# How to use sleep time on another Selenium's driver (with threading) in Pyhton3

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x, selenium

I've been working on two sites and I tried to make use of one driver's sleep time on another Selenium's driver by using threading library but so far it doesn't seem to work in the way I thought it would. So, I'm looking for an explanation, suggestion and fix to my problem.

This is an example code.

```
import threading
from selenium import webdriver
import time

def go_Yahoo():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.yahoo.com/')
    time.sleep(10)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uh-search-box"]').clear()
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uh-search-box"]').send_keys('facebook')
    time.sleep(7)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="uh-search-button"]').click()


def go_Bing():
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    driver.get('https://www.bing.com/')
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sb_form_q"]').clear()
    time.sleep(3)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sb_form_q"]').send_keys('facebook')
    time.sleep(1)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sb_form_go"]').click()

t1 = threading.Thread(target=go_Yahoo())
t2 = threading.Thread(target=go_Bing())
t1.start()
t2.start()
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

So, I thought that while 'go_Yahoo()' was asleep, 'go_Bing()' would kick in. However, I was incorrect somehow. I would like to know why and how I can fix it.

Thx.

Answer (score 0):

If we starting two drives in multi threading mode, it doesn't mean it will run in one step of driver 1 and another step in driver 2, so on. Both will run in parallel if your machine is with dual processors. It can both drivers will be sleep at a time. we can't decide the steps order inside each thread.

if your machine have only one processor then each thread will be executed in allocated processor time in time sliced mode. But It looks like parallel even though it uses single processor.

Even though, we set time.sleep after each step. we don't have control on another thread sleep time.